# body background-image with color twist

Tags: css

Hi guys i created a template which background has  quarter gradient and rest of them are color like this

[image]

example

```
     .left{

          width:30%;
          background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f7fdff, #f6fdff);
          background-repeat:repeat-y;
            }
      .right{
           width:70%;
           background-color:#fff; 
            }
```

and the html is

```
      <body>
       <div class="left"></div>            
       <div class="right"></div>
      </body>
```

and it looks like [image]

Which i need it on full size of screen.  if i did a fixed width means it will change depends on the screen size whats the fix to do it in this kinda situation ?
both sides needs height of 100%.background as double layer left side gradient and right side color as like that images i need it as 100% width and height.I know it won't appear by using div.

Comment: Is your top bar in fixed height?

Comment: @Passerby nope its an default top-bar not positioned as fixed.

Comment: If you want your divs to be the height of the window, you will need `body` to be at least as high as the window too. Otherwise the divs can't calculate what to be as high as. But what's the "situation" with the width? I'm not sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: Then you may need to use flex-box: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: @MrLister leave the top-bar am thinking to create the background as double layer left side gradient and right side color as like that images i need it as 100% width and height.I know it won't appear by using div.

Comment: Ehm... I'm sorry, but I can't read that at all.

Answer (score 0):

For class `left` add `float:left` and `height:100%`.
For class `right` add `float:right`. You can set the `height` for second according to your requirements.

Comment: you can set 100% to both side. Then the second div will take the entire height of the parent container. If you want the same effect as you specified in the image, then you have to reduce the height of the second div according to the parent container height.